# What word conveys the opposite state of "recovery"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If one can be in a state of "recovery" what word conveys an opposite state?

I'm looking for a word that conveys that someone is in a state where they're exerting themselves through physical action. Instead of being in a state of rest—building strength and regaining energy—they're losing it through physical action.

Thank you!

Comment: Context needed.  But I'd hazard a guess at "exhaustion".

Comment: Please hover your pointer over the single-word-request tag to read the additional requirements (written in capitals) for this kind of question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Deterioration**

From [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/recovery), the antonyms of recovery are:

> deterioration
>
> relapse

Since "relapse" implies a period of recovery, I've discarded it.

Where "recovery" implies getting better, "deterioration" implies getting worse, although the mechanism of getting worse isn't explicit. In your example, it could be "wilful deterioration".

Answer (score 2):

> **exertion** noun
>   : the act or an instance of exerting
>   especially : a laborious or perceptible effort
>   <sup>https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exertion</sup>

You are in a state of *exertion* while you are using energy.

Answer (score 2):

"Decline".

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decline):

> : to tend toward an inferior state or weaker condition his health declined Employee morale declined after the layoffs.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is unwell they could "[exacerbate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exacerbate)" or "[aggravate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggravate)" their condition by exerting themselves instead of resting.

These words are usually used in the context of "making a bad situation worse".